# PLINQ AsParallel().ForAll() accessing resource

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, plinq

Suppose I have a number of `Particle`s in X,Y space, and I want to normalise them all such that the average X and Y are 0.

Serial implementation:

```
public void Normalise()
{
  double avgX = 0.0;
  double avgY = 0.0;

  foreach (Particle p in Particles)
  {
    avgX += p.X;
    avgY += p.Y;
  }

  avgX /= (double)Particles.Count;
  avgY /= (double)Particles.Count;

  foreach (Particle p in Particles)
  {
    p.X -= avgX;
    p.Y -= avgY;
  }
}
```

This works, and the performance is not bad since it's O(n), but it's "embarrassingly parallel". Take a look at my PLINQ implementation:

```
public void PNormalise()
{
  double avgX = 0.0;
  double avgY = 0.0;

  Particles.AsParallel().ForAll(p =>
  {
    avgX += p.X;
    avgY += p.Y;
  });

  avgX /= (double)Particles.Count;
  avgY /= (double)Particles.Count;

  Particles.AsParallel().ForAll(p =>
  {
    p.X -= avgX;
    p.Y -= avgY;
  });
}
```

I'm not sure about the performance here, but I would imagine it's better. The problem is, the particles are all jumping around randomly. I can only assume that the `+=` operations on `avgX` and `avgY` are competing against each other, even though they're fairly atomic already.

Is there anything I can do to fix it? I can't `lock` them because they're not objects, but I'm not sure I'd want to anyway because isn't locking quite expensive?

Comment: There's no such thing as “fairly atomic”, an operation either is atomic, or it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bypass the need for a lock (or atomic operations) via the normal machinery of Parallel LINQ:

```
var avgX = Particles.AsParallel().Average(p => p.X);
var avgY = Particles.AsParallel().Average(p => p.Y);

Particles.AsParallel().ForAll(p => { p.X -= avgX; p.Y -= avgY });
```

Since summing the numbers is an O(N) operation, I would be extremely surprised if this part took any significant portion of time.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Particles.AsParallel().ForAll(p =>
{
    Interlocked.Add(avgX, p.X);
    Interlocked.Add(avgY, p.Y);
}
```

to do a thread-safe atomic addition. For more information see the documentation of the [Interlocked Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kczs5b5.aspx).

Comment: A better solution may be to do a Parallel sum which automatically handles this for you.

Comment: `Interlocked.Add` only overloads `(ref int, int)` and `(ref long, long)`, but I'm using `double`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, parallelizing this O(n)-Algorithm won't result in a much better Performance, since you have roughly the same amount of memory accesses as computational instructions.

Comment: I don't know if the JIT complier does it, but it is very possible it could change the instructions to [SIMD instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) via the [SSE processor extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions). [Here is a blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2005/08/15/451845.aspx) with some more information about the CLR and extensions like SSE

Comment: Yes, but the algorithm is still memory bound, so the CPU is still mostly idle, but the few work it is doing is now evenly distributed among its cores.

Comment: @MathiasBecher: O(N) problems like this are actually very nice with parallelism. If your problem size grows bigger, you can, for the most part, throw more hardware at it to perform at a similar level as before. I agree though that it may be a bit trivial unless you have something like N = 10^7.